# No such element: Unable to locate element in C# using Xpath

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, xpath

I'm doing a test for the company i work, i'm kinda new with selenium specially with Xpath, i used id or cssSelector, but with the test i'm doing it i work with a table, so in other post i saw that the best way was using Xpath so i tried, but i got this error
**OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@cssSelector='tr.odd']/td[4]"}**

The test do everything need to do, i use the xpath to get a part of the text in the table, with the next code

```
string textActual = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@cssSelector='tr.odd']/td[4]")).Text;
            Assert.AreEqual("Disabled", textActual);
```

And this is the table:

```
<tbody><tr role="row" class="odd">
<td>Esta es una configuración creada con selenium</td>
<td>030166</td>
<td>Test Selenium</td>
<td>Disabled</td>
<td><button class="button mx-1" onclick="window.location.replace('/TravelTendering/Configuration/Edit/193');" title="Edit"><i class="icon edit"></i></button>
<button onclick="Desactivar(193);" class="button mx-1" title="Delete"><i class="icon trash"></i></button></td></tr>
</tbody>
```

I need the disabled to compare with my assert, but my xpath is wrong and to be honest i don't know why ( if i knew i wouldn't be here)

Comment: .//tr[@class="odd"]/td[4]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing `cssSelector`:

```
tr.odd td:nth-child(4)
```

with `xpath`:

```
.//tr[@class='odd']/td[4]
```

or

```
.//tr[@class='odd']/td[text()='Disabled']
```